# Magento 2.1.2 Update from 2.1 layout XML Problems

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.2

I work in developer mode.

i just update my 2.1 to 2.1.2 by composer! Everything seems ok.
Than after:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod -R 777 pub var
```

I can access without problems the admin Backend. => OK

Than i try to access the category index list => Error

The system.log say:

> [2016-12-17 11:30:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_8d2b930ee1b3294024ee6f3e306d04854 and handles
>   default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_layered,
>   catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children,
>   catalog_category_view_id_3: Bitte korrigieren Sie die XML-Daten und
>   versuchen Sie es erneut.  [] []
>     [2016-12-17 11:30:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_8a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and
>   handles 2columns-left: Bitte korrigieren Sie die XML-Daten und
>   versuchen Sie es erneut.  [] []
>           [2016-12-17 11:30:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_86f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and
>   handles catalog_product_prices: Bitte korrigieren Sie die XML-Daten
>   und versuchen Sie es erneut.  [] []

So .. i dont understand where i have to look! I try to remove this files from
my custom layout .. but this has no effect. The error is the same.

Can it be a problem from the custom extensions?

Hope somebody has a solution!

Comment: It's not errors in most cases. Why do you worry?

Comment: @KAndy can you explain more details? You can leave an answer with more details here.

Comment: My category index list wont render .. only a small part ( broken html ) .. and in this moment this errors are written in the system.log .. so i think that is my problem and i dont understand where i have to look

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue into checkout process. 

@AndreBubner, Did you find any solutions?